# How to test PageReference in testmethod API 27.0

Tags: unit-test, pagereference, apex

My Code coverage is 43%. I am not able to test the Method which returns PageReference method.
In my case method is pass().

```
public static testmethod void test1()
    {    
      String strGUID1 = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('GUID','00000000');
      String strPage1 = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('page','abcd');
      CommonController objCreateServiceOrder = new CommonController();
      objCreateServiceOrder.strGUID = strGUID1;
      objCreateServiceOrder.strPage = strPage1;
      objCreateServiceOrder.pass();
      PageReference pg = Page.ViewQuote;
      pg.getParameters().put('val', 'A');
      pg.getParameters().put('id', 'sdsadsadas');
      pg.getParameters().put('GUID', '000000000');

      Test.setCurrentPage(pg);
      Test.stopTest();
    }

    -------------
 public PageReference pass()
{
    System.debug('inside pass');
    if(strPage != 'CreateCustomer'){
    for (integer i = 0 ; i <  GUID.size() ; i++   )
    {
        if (GUID[i].contains(option))
        {
            //system.debug('GUID[i]: ' + GUID[i] + ' OPTION : ' + option);
             if (GUID[i].contains('@'))
             {
                        String [] Prefixess =  GUID[i].split('@');
                        system.debug('Prefix[0]: ' + Prefixess[1]); 
                        if(Prefixess[0] == option){
                        preGUID = Prefixess[1];
                        break;
                        }
             }
             else
             {
                        preGUID = GUID[i];
                        //system.debug('GUID[i]: ' + GUID[i] + ' OPTION : ' + option);
                        break;
             }

        }
        }
    }

    PageReference pg;

    if (strPage.contains('ViewQuote'))
    {
         pg = new PageReference('/apex/ViewQuote?val=' + option+'&GUID='+preGUID+'&id='+ID);
    }
    else if (strPage.contains('InstantOrder'))
    {    
       pg = new PageReference('/apex/InstantOrder?val=' + option+'&GUID='+preGUID+'&id='+ID);
    }
    else if (strPage.contains('NewOrderNewQuote'))
    {
        pg = new PageReference('/apex/NewOrderNewQuote?val=' + option+'&GUID='+preGUID+'&id='+ID);
    }
    else if (strPage.contains('ViewOrderHistory'))
    {
        pg = new PageReference('/apex/ViewOrderHistory?val=' + option+'&GUID='+preGUID+'&id='+ID);
    }
    else if(strPage.contains('CreateCustomer')){
    System.debug('CreateCustomer : ' + option);
    if(option != null || option != ''){
    pg = new PageReference('/apex/SyncAccount?val=' + option + '&id=' + ID);
    System.debug('/apex/SyncAccount?val=' + option + '&id=' + ID);
    }
    }
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of  "strPage" variable different type and the need to call pass() method every time. then that line will be covered.

```
public static testmethod void test1()
        {    
          String strGUID1 = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('GUID','00000000');
          String strPage1 = 



    ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('page','abcd');
          CommonController objCreateServiceOrder = new CommonController();
          objCreateServiceOrder.strGUID = strGUID1;

          objCreateServiceOrder.strPage = 'ViewQuote';
          objCreateServiceOrder.pass();

          objCreateServiceOrder.strPage = 'InstantOrder';
          objCreateServiceOrder.pass();

          objCreateServiceOrder.strPage = 'NewOrderNewQuote';
          objCreateServiceOrder.pass();

          objCreateServiceOrder.strPage = 'ViewOrderHistory'";
          objCreateServiceOrder.pass();

          objCreateServiceOrder.strPage = strPage1;
          objCreateServiceOrder.pass();

          PageReference pg = Page.ViewQuote;
          pg.getParameters().put('val', 'A');
          pg.getParameters().put('id', 'sdsadsadas');
          pg.getParameters().put('GUID', '000000000');

          Test.setCurrentPage(pg);
          Test.stopTest();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response D-Horse, I copied the whole test method you provided but it is still on 43%. Still showing those red lines.

Comment: I think now test class is covering your pagereferences and now you have to provide data to  your class according to code for that you have write more test function.

Comment: I am passing all data from the test method and my all class properties are in blue, PageReference codes are in red. I also coverd all Methods.

Comment: In your pass method there is variable strPage  you need to provide the value like InstantOrder,strPage1 etc call pass method then again .

Comment: Can you please edit the answer , so I can get clear idea.